Unsure if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(5 + \cos n)^n}$ converges or diverges
I am unsure if the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(5 + \cos n)^n}$$ converges or diverges.
I know that $5+\cos n$ lies between $5-1^n=4$ and $5+1^n=6$, meaning that we can bound the expression as $\frac{1}{4^n} \geq \frac{1}{(3 + \cos n)^n} \geq \frac{1}{6^n}$.
Taking $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{4^n}=\frac{1}{3}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{4^n}=\frac{1}{5}$, we get the bound as $\frac{1}{3}\geq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(3 + \cos n)^n} \geq \frac{1}{6}$. But this still does not prove convergence since $\frac{1}{3}$ does not equal $\frac{1}{6}$?
If that is the case and the sequence diverges, how should I best show that the sequence diverges in a formal proof?

$(5+\cos n)^n$ is always positive

You can use limit comparison test: compare it with 1/5^n

Series with non-negative summands  converges if and only if its partial sums is bounded. In fact, this isn't limited to one dimension sum. it is true for any multi-dimension sum. Furthermore, the "limit" is independent of order of summation and equals to the supremum of the set of finite sums.

What about the series $$\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac 1{(5-1)^n}\ ,\qquad \sum_{n\ge 1}\frac 1{(5+1)^n}\ ?$$Than buy a sandwich!

Root test also works https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test.

There exists a nice and useful sandwich theorem for series

Given series $\sum a_n<\infty$ and $\sum c_n<\infty$ and $a_n \le b_n \le c_n$ then $\sum b_n<\infty$.

The proof is straighforward, indeed
$$a_n \le b_n \le c_n \iff 0\le b_n-a_b\le c_n-a_n$$
then by direct comparison test
$$\sum (c_n-a_n)<\infty \implies\sum (b_n-a_n)<\infty $$
and since
$$\sum b_n= \sum (b_n-a_n)+\sum a_n$$
we also have $\sum b_n<\infty$.
The theorem applies to this case by $a_n=\frac{1}{6^n}$, $b_n=\frac{1}{(5 + \cos n)^n}$ and $c_n=\frac{1}{4^n}$.
